# Tmux to create a window if it doesn't exist yet

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to configure `tmux` so that when you want to switch to a window that doesn't exist, it creates the window and then switches (avoiding Ctrl-b c) ?

Answer (score 11):

Add this to `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key 0 if-shell 'tmux select-window -t :0' '' 'new-window -t :0'
```

This will first attempt to switch to window 0, and if that failed, create it.

Repeat for 1-9.

Comment: @user3244608 Welcome to Stack Exchange! If an answer fully solves your problem, please mark it as accepted by ticking the check mark next to it. For more information, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I made my solution based on @JigglyNaga's approach:

```
bind -n M-S-Right  run-shell 'current_window=$(tmux display-message -p '#I'); next_window=$(($current_window + 1)); tmux select-window -t :$next_window; if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then tmux new-window -t :$next_window; fi'
```

When you want to go to the next window, it checks if it exists, then move on. If it doesn't, create a new one and move on.

You also need to set this:

```
set -g renumber-windows on
```